# Visual Studio 2015 (C#): web deploy package including all the third parties files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I am working with Visual Studio 2015 (C#). I have created a project containing an ASP.NET web site project and a web application. The web application contains a web service that is used in my web site (I added the service as a service reference in my web site) . I want to publish my website as a web deploy package, and then import this package in another computer of the local network using IIS 8. However, whenever I import this package in another computer, the files of the web application are missing. How can I instruct Visual Studio 2015 to create a deployment packages containing all the files of my website and all the files of the web application?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on your web project and select properties you will see an option on the left called Package/Publish Web.  In that screen you can select a drop down for Items to deploy.

It sounds like you are wanting to select "All files in this project folder".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed you advice. Now when I publish my website from visual studio using the "web deploy package" option, I find five files in the App_WebReferences/MyWebservice folder of my zipped package: configuration.svcinfo, configuration91.svcinfo, MyService.disco, MyService.wdsl and Reference.svcmap. But when I try to import my zipped package in IIS 8 using web deploy 3, and that i run it, I get the following error: "[EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at...". It seems like all the required files were still not copied. Should I also copy dll files?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't have more to offer.  I have not done a package before, my settings work for a plain web deploy.  However I did find this walkthough online which may help you.  Check the spot with the heading **Requirement 2**.  http://jpsmit.bloggingabout.net/2012/06/04/deploying-wcf-services-using-web-deploy/

Comment: i was so far down a msbuild rabbit hole i could hardly breathe.  this unassuming answer saved me so much headache. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to specify which specific files to add?